# writing to and reading from window.localStorage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I've worked with localStorage across multiple windows before without any problems, but for some reason in this new application it is not working at all.

I have two pages, PageA and PageB. PageA sets some data in localStorage like so:

```
var someData = {
    item1: 'foo',
    item2: 'bar'
};
window.localStorage.setItem('someKey', JSON.stringify(someData));
```

If I immediately try to read the data via `JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('someKey'));`, it works fine.

PageA then calls a `window.open(PageBURL)` to open PageB. In PageB, when I attempt to read the value from localStorage, all I get is `null`:

```
JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('someKey')); // gives me null
```

Both pages have identical `document.domain` values. There must be something stupid I am missing, does anyone have any ideas of things to double check?

Comment: That's really, really strange. Is it consistent across multiple browsers? I tried what you describe, copy/pasting your code verbatim -  it works just fine. (running from both file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/enhzflep/pageA.html and /localhost/enhzflep/pageA.html) - works as is in chrome, needs "window." removed in IE9, works fine in Opera, IE and Chrome with it removed.

Comment: Try using something like [amplify](http://amplifyjs.com/) to make things simpler in a cross browser environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out `localStorage` runs under the full host domain, not the javascript `document.domain`.

PageA runs under `"foo.common.net"` with a `document.domain` of `"common.net"`.

PageB runs under `"bar.common.net"` with a `document.domain` of `"common.net"`.

If I switch PageA to run under `"bar.common.net"`, I am able to read the data without a problem.

Comment: @drderp i am not allowed to accept my own answer for a 2 day period, in case someone else posts a better solution.

Comment: I've never run into this, I didn't realize there was a time limit on that, sorry.